# Need tip for css layout

Tags: html, css

```
,----------------------------------------------.
|,-----------------------. ,------------------.|
|| <input>               | |                  ||
|`-----------------------' |                  ||
|,-----------------------. |     <img>        ||
|| <input>               | | aspect ratio 1:1 ||
|`-----------------------' |                  ||
|,-----------------------. |                  ||
|| <input>               | |                  ||
|`-----------------------' `------------------'|
`----------------------------------------------'
```

I want to layout something like above with constraints:

- height is constrained by 3 input fields, i.e. `height = 3 * input_height + 2 * margin`
- `<img>` should fulfill the height, i.e. `img_height = height`
- `<img>` has a constant aspect ratio of 1, so its width is constrained, i.e. `img_width = img_height = height`
- `<input>`'s width can be constrained by `input_width = width - img_width`
- parent width is fixed `width = some_fixed_value`

I want to achieve this with pure css, is this possible? and how?

I'm newbie to web so not so familiar with css layout. I've done some search and it seems like height can't be a primitive constraint (just a guess according to what I got).

Thanks.

Comment: Consider using flexbox, with two elements (inputs and image), and use another nested flexbox for the images.

Comment: Since you didn't mention avoid using `<table>`, it's possible to achieve this with simple HTML table...

Comment: @torazaburo, thanks, I tried to use and didn't figure out how to achieve `img_wdith = img_height`

Comment: @Raptor, thanks, How to set aspect ratio to 1: 1 using table?

Comment: Try [this](https://jsfiddle.net/052p6y01/)

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the greatest (personally, I think if I spent more time on it, it would be better), but if you only want to use CSS, this should do the trick:

```
<style>

div#main {
    background: tan;
    padding: 5px;
    height: 250px;
    display:inline-block;
}

#input-container {
    height: 100%;
    margin-right: 5px;
    width: auto;
    float: left;
    display:inline-block;
}

input {
    height: 28%;
    width: 250px;
    margin: 1% 0 1% 0;
}

#img-container {
    height: 100%;
    display:inline-block;
}

#image {
    height: 100%;
}

</style>


<div id="main">
    <div id="input-container">
        <input><br>
        <input><br>
        <input><br>
    </div>
    <div id="img-container">
        <img src="path\to\image.jpg" id="image">
    </div>
</div>
```

This may not be exactly what you were trying to achieve, but it might work. Unfortunately, this will be a bit finicky when it comes to changing the height and width of `div#main` because many of the heights and widths of other elements will not automatically fill to the parent element's height. Basically, this means it won't work if you plan on allowing the size of the inputs/image/main to change when in a browser (i.e. using percentages).

Alternatively, you could use tables to contain the inputs, like so:

```
<style>

div#main {
    background: tan;
    padding: 5px;
    display:inline-block;
}

table {
    height: 100%;
    margin-right: 5px;
    width: auto;
    float: left;
    display:inline-block;
}


td {
    padding: 0px;
}

input {
    height: 20px; /*Change this value*/
    width: 250px;
    margin: 1% 0 1% 0;
}

#img-container {
    height: 100px; /*And change this*/
    display:inline-block;
}

#image {
    height: 100%;
}

</style>


<div id="main">
    <table>
            <tr>
                <td><input><br></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input><br></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input><br></td>
            </tr>
    </table>
    <div id="img-container">
        <img src="path\to\image.jpg" id="image">
    </div>
</div>
```

I couldn't find a way to get the image to automatically resize for this one, so you must change the size of the inputs and the image separately.